Get AD groups a user is member of from all domains and subdomains
I am trying to get all the groups a user is a member of in all my domains and subdomains.
Here is the setup :
Forest 1
domain1.local
sub.domain1.local
Forest 2
domain2.local
The user is located in domain1.local and I have managed to get all the groups in both domain1.local and domain2.local, but am unable to get the groups from sub.domain1.local. 
Here is what I have :
$domain1user = Get-ADUser -Server DC.domain1.local -Filter "Name -like 'John Doe'"
$domain1groups = Get-ADUser -Identity $domain1user -Server DC.domain1.local -Credential $myCreds -Properties MemberOf | Select-Object -ExpandProperty MemberOf

$domain2user = "CN=$($domain1user.SID.Value),CN=ForeignSecurityPrincipals,DC=domain2,DC=local"
$domain2groups = (Get-ADObject -Identity $domain2user -Server DC.domain2.local -Credential $myCreds -Properties MemberOf).MemberOf

If I try something like this to get the groups from the subdomain :
$subdomaingroups = (Get-ADObject -Identity $domain1user -Server DC.sub.domain1.local -Credential $myCreds -Properties MemberOf).MemberOf

I get this error.

Get-ADObject : A referral was returned from the server 
CategoryInfo : ResourceUnavailable: (CN=John Doe,OU=...DC=domain1,DC=local:ADUser)  [Get-ADObject], ADReferralException 

The only method I have working so far is to grab all the groups of the subdomain and check every single one if the user is a member of that group. I would like to use a simpler way if possible.
Thanks.

I found the way, I was using the wrong approach. Get-ADGroup was the correct way to do this.
$domain1groups   = Get-ADGroup -Server dc.domain1.local -Credential $myCreds -Filter * -Properties Members | Where-Object { $_.Members -contains $domain1user }
$subdomaingroups = Get-ADGroup -Server dc.sub.domain1.local -Credential $myCreds -Filter * -Properties Members | Where-Object { $_.Members -contains $domain1user }
$domain2groups   = Get-ADGroup -Server dc.domain2.local -Credential $myCreds -Filter * -Properties Members | Where-Object { $_.Members -contains $domain2user }

